# How to group row values based on same column name

Tags: mysql

I have created the schema and query on SQL Fiddle:
SQL Fiddle(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e43a13/1)

I am trying to get prices of work type according to the urgency and academic level, I am successful in getting that but I can't figure out how to format it in this way:

```
| Urgency | Academic Level Name 1   |      Academic Level 2    |     Academic Level 3     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 hour  |Price Of Academic Level 1|Price Of Academic Level 2 | Price Of Academic Level 3|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have as the output:

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to `group by urgency`, you may consider below query.

```
SELECT 
    utt.UrgencyTime as `Urgency`   
    , sum(case when al.AcademicID = 1 then wtd.Price else 0 end) as `Academic Level Name 1`
    , sum(case when al.AcademicID = 2 then wtd.Price else 0 end) as `Academic Level Name 2`
    , sum(case when al.AcademicID >= 3 then wtd.Price else 0 end) as `Academic Level Name 3`
FROM `WorkTypeData` wtd
JOIN UrgencyTimeTable utt ON utt.UrgencyID = wtd.UrgencyID
JOIN WorkType wt ON wt.WorkTypeID = wtd.WorkTypeID
JOIN AcademicLevel al ON al.AcademicID = wtd.AcademicLevelID
WHERE wt.WorkTypeID = '1' 
GROUP BY utt.UrgencyTime
```

Comment: Hey Metal, the academic levels are dynamic not every work type has the same academic levels. I cannot use cases like this

Comment: Hey Metal, please help me. I can't figure out the solution

Comment: But how do we know if it belongs to academic level 1?

Comment: please have a look at my table structure of academic level at sql fiddle

Comment: You can ignore it, but You might have multiple Price

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203004/discussion-between--and-uzair).

Comment: when I remove the sum function it returns 0

Answer (score 0):

to get prices of work type according to the urgency and academic level, use the following query,

```
SELECT 
utt.UrgencyTime as Urgency, 
al.LevelName as "Academic Level Name",
wtd.Price 
FROM `WorkTypeData` wtd
            JOIN
            UrgencyTimeTable utt
            ON
            utt.UrgencyID = wtd.UrgencyID
            JOIN
            WorkType wt
            ON
            wt.WorkTypeID = wtd.WorkTypeID
            JOIN
            AcademicLevel al
            ON
            al.AcademicID = wtd.AcademicLevelID
            WHERE wt.WorkTypeID = '1' 
            group by utt.UrgencyTime, al.LevelName
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think this might be helpful

```
SELECT
    utt.UrgencyTime AS `Urgency` ,
CASE
        WHEN al.AcademicID = 1 THEN wtd.Price
        ELSE 0
END AS `Academic LEVEL Name 1` ,
CASE
        WHEN al.AcademicID = 2 THEN wtd.Price
        ELSE 0
END AS `Academic LEVEL Name 2` ,
CASE
        WHEN al.AcademicID = 7 THEN wtd.Price
        ELSE 0
END AS `Academic LEVEL Name 7` ,
CASE
        WHEN al.AcademicID = 8 THEN wtd.Price
        ELSE 0
END AS `Academic LEVEL Name 8` ,
CASE
        WHEN al.AcademicID = 9 THEN wtd.Price
        ELSE 0
END AS `Academic LEVEL Name 9`
FROM
    `WorkTypeData` wtd
JOIN UrgencyTimeTable utt ON utt.UrgencyID = wtd.UrgencyID
JOIN WorkType wt ON wt.WorkTypeID = wtd.WorkTypeID
JOIN AcademicLevel al ON al.AcademicID = wtd.AcademicLevelID
group  BY utt.UrgencyTime, al.AcademicID
```